Next-intl invalid locale guard not working as app/[locale]/[[...slug]]/page.tsx & child components executes before app/[locale]/layout.tsx
If you follow next-intl documentation you basically set a "guard" in app/[locale]/layout.tsx
if (!locale || !locales.includes(locale)) {
  notFound()
}

So I'd expect it to end there and never hit child route segments.
But what's really happening is that app/[locale]/[[...slug]]/page.tsx and it's child server components executes first - doing all sorts of unnecessary fetching and processing, if the url was simply a domain.com/some-image-that-does-not-exist.png
Sure the not-found.tsx page shows, but how can I avoid all this unnecessary data fetching and work in general from the child components that should never have been executed?
I just want to hit the 404 based on the url - in this case it's for an image (with dot in its name) which is not 307 redirected with a locale in front of it - thus it should simply end at the 404 page (due to no locale in front).
Using Next 14 and app router.
There's an open issue in the next.js repo on github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/53026
